# Seaborn heatmap - colorbar label font size

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How do I set the font size of the colorbar label?

```
ax=sns.heatmap(table, vmin=60, vmax=100, xticklabels=[4,8,16,32,64,128],yticklabels=[2,4,6,8], cmap="PuBu",linewidths=.0, 
        annot=True,cbar_kws={'label': 'Accuracy %'}
```

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately seaborn does not give access to the objects it creates. So one needs to take the detour, using the fact that the colorbar is an axes in the current figure and that it is the last one created, hence

```
ax = sns.heatmap(...)
cbar_axes = ax.figure.axes[-1]
```

For this axes, we may set the fontsize by getting the ylabel using its `set_size` method.

Example, setting the fontsize to 20 points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns
data = np.random.rand(10, 12)*100
ax = sns.heatmap(data, cbar_kws={'label': 'Accuracy %'})
ax.figure.axes[-1].yaxis.label.set_size(20)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the same can of course be achieved by via

```
ax = sns.heatmap(data)
ax.figure.axes[-1].set_ylabel('Accuracy %', size=20)
```

without the keyword argument passing.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. What about the annotation format? Do you know how to change it?

Comment: That would be obvious from [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could also explicitly pass in the axes objects into `heatmap` and modify them directly:

```
grid_spec = {"width_ratios": (.9, .05)}
f, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(1,2, gridspec_kw=grid_spec) 
sns.heatmap(data, ax=ax, cbar_ax=cbar_ax, cbar_kws={'label': 'Accuracy %'})
cbar_ax.yaxis.label.set_size(20)
```